# Python eve method as a default value provider for field

Tags: python, eve

I have a basic schema that I'm messing with to see if eve is a good match for what I need. My question is whether I can set a default value for a field by using a method, also with params would be awesome though I doubt it's possible.

Something like:

```
from utils import generate_token

...
    'token': {
        'type': 'string',
        'default': generate_token,
        'unique': True,
        'required': True,
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [new release](http://nicolaiarocci.com/cerberus-0-9-has-been-released/) of Cerberus (0.9) I managed to find a hack into this matter and specify 'coerce' which is a callable being applied to the value before the validation takes place so I just went ahead with the following which works as I need it:

```
'token': {
    'type': 'string',
    'default': None,
    'coerce': generate_token,
    'unique': True,
    'readonly': True
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's a nice usage for the brand new Cerberus  `coerce` rule. Well done.